# add android lib project as reference to app engine project

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have created an android project, with a library project to go along with it.  I'd now like to build a backend for the android app using google app engine.  There are some classes etc in the android lib project that I'd like to use in the new app engine project.  What is the best way to setup that dependency?  If it helps, I'm using IntelliJ...

thx
Ben

Answer (score 0):

may be this one help you..

If you create the `.jar` file of your project then put that jar in your libs folder of new project and use them. Or you can just copy-past your packages into you project.